# Connect C wire to Carrier board

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, central-air

I got Carrier board HK61EA010 and extra C-blue wire that is not connected to the board. I wanna use this wire to power WI-FI thermostat. I cannot find the manual for this board. Does anyone know where C wire supposed to be connected on this board?

[image]

Comment: What model is the actual furnace?

Comment: You didn’t give much info but I don’t think you are looking at the right circuit board. Find the transformer and trace where the two low voltage wires go. One will trace back to the power wire on the thermostat and the other will be the common. Without more info that’s the best I can do.